# How to remove Mega-Menu dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, phtml, menu, list.phtml

I want to (Magento ver. 1.9.2.3) default menu in my other phtml file. how to call it?
 I want to display menu onclick

[image: display on hover]

Answer (score 1):

The menu is just a `phtml` file, so basically all you need to do is make sure you create a new block within you `layout.xml` to add this block there as well. Only thing you need to keep in mind is that you should give it a unique name and maybe call it within the parent's template file using `$this->getChildHtml('my_menu_name');`.

After that you might have to do some styling, because it might be that the menu is styled with selectors that are unique for the header or something.